# Get specific value within a file in python

Tags: python, file, grep

Hello I have a file such as

```
line .....
line ...content....

SEs for parameters:
0.290391 0.273460 0.236199 0.177329 0.205789 0.221322 0.283763 0.133840 0.119349 0.161495 0.166068 0.340432 0.267828 0.211030 0.175328 0.201448 0.172427 0.244625 0.118869 0.070389 0.085757 0.121992 0.295142 0.371023 0.286122 0.114233 0.191837 0.086125 0.119095 0.061429 0.116536 0.030760 0.018447

contennn

llinnee
some stuf ...
```

and I would like to get the last value after the `SEs for parameters:` match (0.018447)

and save it into a variable called  :`Number`

than I should get

```
print (Number)
0.018447
```

does someone have an idea using python3 ?

Comment: Read the lines in a loop, checking whether the line matches `SEs for parameters:`. When you find that line, read the next line, split it on whitespace, and print the last element.

Comment: Is that a single line of numbers after `SEs for parameters:` or multiple lines?

Comment: it is a single one

Comment: If it is indeed a single line, you could use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/XWaXgi/1) and group 1 will have your value

Answer (score 0):

Well I found by using :

```
with open("path/file.txt", "r") as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        if line.startswith("SEs for parameters:"):
            SE=next(ifile, ' ').strip()
            Number=re.split('\s+', SE)
            print(SE[-1])
```

Comment: You don't need to use `re.split`. Just use `Number = SE.split()`. And I think you mean `Number[-1]` at the end.